SnaphuExport Error "org.esa.snap.core.gpf.OperatorException warning"
I am using the snap program for a project. I have gradually completed the project stages. However, I am getting an error somewhere. When I want to do Snaphu Export, I get the org.esa.snap.core.gpf.OperatorException warning.
My error code:
java.io.IOException: SNAPHU writer requires a wrapped phase band
 at org.jlinda.nest.dataio.SnaphuWriter.writeUnwrappedBandHeader(SnaphuWriter.java:105)
 at org.jlinda.nest.dataio.SnaphuWriter.writeProductNodesImpl(SnaphuWriter.java:74)
 at org.esa.snap.core.dataio.AbstractProductWriter.writeProductNodes(AbstractProductWriter.java:111)
 at org.jlinda.nest.dataio.SnaphuExportOp.writeHeader(SnaphuExportOp.java:214)
 at org.jlinda.nest.dataio.SnaphuExportOp.computeTile(SnaphuExportOp.java:194)
Caused: org.esa.snap.core.gpf.OperatorException: SNAPHU writer requires a wrapped phase band
 at org.jlinda.nest.dataio.SnaphuExportOp.computeTile(SnaphuExportOp.java:206)
 at org.esa.snap.core.gpf.internal.OperatorImage.computeRect(OperatorImage.java:82)
[catch] at javax.media.jai.SourcelessOpImage.computeTile(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler.scheduleTile(Unknown Source)
 at javax.media.jai.OpImage.getTile(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.media.jai.util.RequestJob.compute(Unknown Source)
 horse com.sun.media.jai.util.WorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)

After encountering this error, I did the following:

I reviewed the forum pages
I checked the snaphu versions
I added the snaphu .bin file from the advanced system settings
I checked snaphu from the Manage Externol Tool page.

I could not solve the problem.
